# In the context of a blockchain-based digital currency, I have some questions regarding the functionality and operations of a particular system

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, cryptocurrency

- Could you clarify where the stack object is typically generated? Is it created on the sender's device or the recipient's device?
- If I send funds to a multipay stack that was created on another device currently offline, what would happen? Would the payments defined by the stack be delayed until the offline device is back online?

Additionally, I came across a discussion about the mechanics of this currency. One statement mentioned the importance of honoring a rule to ensure proper functioning:

"Only if the amount at the liquidity stack input reaches the stack internal threshold, the observer considers that liquidity stack as triggered. After triggering, the threshold amount is moved to stack output, and a stack transaction connects the liquidity stack to liquidity stack change. If users didn't honor this rule then the currency couldn't function as intended. That's why all users do honor the rule."

- I'm trying to understand how the stack facilitates the transfer of funds to two addresses. In Haircomb, my understanding was that only one directed edge could originate from an address. Could you explain how this splitting of funds is achieved within the stack?
- Who exactly is referred to as "the observer" who determines when a stack should trigger? Is it a centralized entity or a decentralized mechanism?
- When it's mentioned that "all users honor the rule," does it imply that all users can verify the correct splitting of funds within the stack? Considering that the input amount may be hidden from most users, how can they trust the outcome without having visibility into it? Is this trust primarily placed in the user who owns the stack object?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

- The stack object is typically created on the payer's machine.
- If a multipay stack is offline, payments defined by the stack will be delayed until it comes back online.
- The stack enables fund splitting through internal mechanisms within the currency.
- "The observer" refers to a decentralized mechanism rather than a centralized entity.
- "All users honor the rule" means they all follow the consensus.